# Fluent NHibernate not return distinct values

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have code calling on a list of groups that have a one to many relationship with Users through a table called GroupToUsers.

I'm trying to list distinct list of groups that contains the list of users within each group.

I'm new to NHibernate so please be patient :).

Code:

```
IQueryOver<Group, Group> query = this.Session.QueryOver<Group>()
    .Where(g => g.IsActive && !g.IsDeleted)
    .Fetch(g => g.Users).Eager
    .JoinAlias(g => g.Users, () => groupToUser, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
    .Where(g => g.Owner.Id == userId || (groupToUser.Group != null && groupToUser.IsAccepted && groupToUser.Profile.Id == userId))
    .OrderBy(g => g.Description).Asc
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);
        IQueryOver<Group> countQuery = query.ToRowCountQuery().Cacheable();
        IFutureValue<int> totalCount = countQuery.FutureValue<int>();

        result.Items = query.Take(size + 1).Skip((page - 1) * size).List();
        result.Count = totalCount.Value;
```

I'm expecting 9 records but it's return a count of 11 (which there are 11 rows 2 group repeated twice as they each have 2 users each)

So my question is why is it that result.Count is returning 11 count instead of 9?

Comment: If you are new to NHibernate, was using [tag:queryover] rather than [tag:linq-to-nhibernate] a deliberate choice? Many newcomers go ahead with QueryOver believing it is the NHibernate "linq" because of lambda usage, but no, it is something else.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the point, saying that the count is extended with each user record in the `Users` collection. This is the result of the `.Fetch()` call.

There are two queries. The first *(original with the transformation)* and the second, just a call to get the *count*. The problem is, that the second query is not calling the

```
.TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);
```

(as the first does). It is just a clone of the previous query *(without order by)* and that's why it does return the real 11.

In general. I would suggest, do not use fetching over the mapped collections. This has these side effects... e.g. the unpredictable paging *(the `Take()` and `Skip()` would be applied on the DB side, while the Distinct root on the client/app server)*

What is the way, I would prefer, and using long time, is to use the batch-fetching. That means, change the mapping like described here: [19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)

Using the Fluent mapping you have to update your Users mapping like this

```
HasMany(x => x.Users)
  ...
  .BatchSize(25);
```

And there will be executed at least two queries (maybe 3)... one for root entity, one for the collection items (users) .. but not for each root element, but as a batch. So, not all in once, but still very efficient